# Volume controls suddenly became disabled. What could happen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, volume-control, prestigio-multipad

Most of volume controls on my  [PRESTIGIO PMP5080CPRO](https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=120224062106279356&THEME=asbis&LANG=en) android 4 tablet became disabled (all except alarm volume control). And there are no sound except alarms. What could happen? How can I enable them ? I haven't installed anything recently. Here are screenshots:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: @Poldie, 2nd screenshot narrows everything perfectly

Comment: @HongKilDong except that it still doesn't tell us which device it is. I don't think everybody can tell that from some "Model number".

Comment: @Izzy, how can I describe device more than google can ? What information should I provide ?

Comment: That's a model number; analogous to saying "I have a gt-i9300" when it would be a lot more meaningful to say "I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (international model)".  No-one else is going to Google that for you if you can't be bothered to.

Comment: @HongKilDong Exactly as you did with your update (thanks) :) Additionally, for non-mainstream devices, a link is often helpful.